# Cannot get the Public Key

Tags: ssh, git

I am taking a course which is instructing me to get a Public hey but I keep getting an error.  Please explain it as simple as possible.  Thank you in advance.  I'm pasting what the errors below:

```
Gwendoria@Gwencomputer MINGW64 ~
$ git config --global user.name "Del Harrison"

Gwendoria@Gwencomputer MINGW64 ~
$ git config --global user.email "delchong@yahoo.com"

Gwendoria@Gwencomputer MINGW64 ~
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "delchong@yahoo.com"
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/c/Users/Gwendoria/.ssh/id_rsa): vi~
vi~ already exists.
Overwrite (y/n)? y
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in vi~
Your public key has been saved in vi~.pub
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:a+9Ul5lTFcfmYNZdBMU7SkDi1BJX0ogfW6p2OzYK5G4 delchong@yahoo.com
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 3072]----+
|         +=++..OX|
|        ooo=.o+ O|
|         .o *o +o|
|           + . B.|
|       .S . o B .|
|      o  + o o . |
|       o+ o .    |
|      .E.o =     |
|      .. o= o    |
+----[SHA256]-----+

Gwendoria@Gwencomputer MINGW64 ~
$ ssh -T git@github.com
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Answer (score 1):

in your git terminal  type

```bsh
cat /c/Users/Gwendoria/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

then copy the output to your clipboard, beginning with

> ssh-rsa

and likely ending with

> = Gwendoria@Gwencomputer

Log into your github account in the browser. In the far upper right click your avatar and select settings from the dropdown menu.

In settings, in the left menu bar select

> SSH and GPG keys

Then select

> New SSH Key

Paste the key in from your clipboard. Give It a Title. Click Add SSH key.

More info here:

https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account